# Meteor iron-router .go without refreshing the site

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I want to use Router.go('...') function to navigate via javascript after e.g. submitting form. Is it possible to do so without refreshing the whole site ? Refresh wouldn't be such a problem, problem is that refresh forces to quit all alerts, so e.g. when user submits form and everything went well, he will get alert and then I want to move him onto another site (with Router.go('...')), but after using this function site refreshes and alert quits.
For alerts I'm using sAlert package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an onClose callback event in the s-alert package you can use:
https://github.com/juliancwirko/meteor-s-alert#callback-onclose

Just pass a function that has your Router.go into that property of the alert.

Comment: Thanks ! I haven't realized sAlert package has such property. Will try it out !

Answer (score 1):

Within the event of submitting a form, you can prevent the default browser behaviour, one of which is the page refresh.

You can do so like this.

```
    Template.myTemplate.events({
            'click': function(event) { // whichever class is used to trigger the submit function
                    event.preventDefault(); // prevent browser default behavior, i.e. refresh for on submit in forms
             // rest of your code
             // Router.go('nameOfRoute');
            }
    });
```

With regards to keeping the state of data the same after navigating, you can use [sessions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session). Do also keep in mind that Session variables sit on the global space on the client.